# Sort multiple of 4 grid, in subsequently smaller quads

Tags: python, mesh

I’m working on a custom exported for Blender 3.3. I have groups of faces grouped using Face Maps, these groups are always multiples of 4.
I would like to export these faces by iterating through the FaceMaps and then exporting then by grouping them in subsequently smaller quad-shapes.

So for example, if the following picture, I would like to group first the red quad, then the green one, then the blue one and finally the yellow one.

[image]

I can iterate through the vertices of the Facemap and retrieve the ones that are not duplicated, so then I can check which face is in the corner, so I can pick one of those faces to start this process.

Once I have that face I can compare the center point of this face with the other faces and determine for example which one is closest to the right, and then bottom for those two.

But that approach has many issues, depending on which corner I start first and which face I pick after I’m done with each subquad.

There must be a cleaner and simpler solution but I cannot think of any.
Does anyone have any suggestions or hints for a different approach?